# How do I install and target a specific version of Nitrous.io?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, nitrousio

Just a quick question using nitrous.io. Been following a tutorial on treehouse for ruby on rails, now as they use version 3.2 and I was using 4 it just was impossible to follow.

So, how do I choose which version of Nitrous.io I'm installing / targeting? I need to be using 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick and easy way to handle this would be to install Rails 3.2 alongside with Rails 4.

```
gem install rails -v 3.2
```

From there, you can create a new project with Rails 3.2 with the following command:

```
gem _3.2_ new appname
```

If you are working on an existing project, ensure your `Gemfile` is specifying `gem 'rails', '3.2.0'`, and from there you can run `bundle install` to ensure all dependencies have been installed.